# Make an Earth Sphere

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm new to Blender and I need to create a model of spherical earth with all the countries as separate meshes.

For now I've managed to create a flat map of the earth with separate countries from a shapefile, but I'm not really sure what to do next. I've read plenty of stuff in Internet, but couldn't find anything that will help me to get a desirable result (globe with separate meshes as countries).

Is it actually possible with blender? Any ideas and suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: Off topic (and directed to those who are too quick to judge others), but I have a quick complaint: I think it is quite inappropriate to downvote a new contributor's question right away, instead of helping him with an obvious question and maybe helping a little bit to formulate the question better! Please be nice to each other and help if you don't like something and you can do it better!

Comment: Back to Topic: @Elmpt, what would be your approach so far? Can you explain a little more with pictures? What have you tried so far and what specific questions have arisen?

Answer (score 2):

I close the question.
Apparently I found a nice tool from domlysz called BlenderGIS: https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/wiki/Make-an-earth-globe
And it has a nice function to transform lon/lat data from shapefile to sphere.
Thank you @quellenform for your comment!

Comment: Btw: If you want to use *SRTM data* (elevation data) with *BlenderGIS*, then you need an ID at OpenTopography. Just [register](https://portal.opentopography.org/newUser) your account and attach the *ApiKey* to the URLs, or use a [modified version](https://github.com/lobnico/BlenderGIS) of *BlenderGIS* where you can define the *ApiKey* directly in the settings.

Comment: @Elmpt Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and procedure. Can you [edit] your post and provide some more details about the workflow and how it to use the mentioned addon? Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)